# Bitpay for Ethereum?

Tags: exchanges, coinbase

I'd like to help an organization accept Ethereum. However, they need a Bitpay-type service that sends them USD right away.

I know they can just manually sell on Coinbase daily/weekly, but they can't actually hold ETH at any point for various reasons so that seems to be out of the question.

Is there a service that lets you accept ETH and sends you USD?

An automatic-sell feature on an exchange might be sufficient, but doesn't seem possible with coinbase.

Answer (score 1):

**Coinify** does *next day settlements*, their accepted currencies include **ETH**, BTC, LTC and DOGE at time of writing; you can check here thru their API: https://api.coinify.com/v3/input-currencies

OP mentions Ethereum specifically, however **if OP is just looking for any altcoin** to avoid Bitcoin's slow and expensive transactions, then BitPay now accepts Bitcoin Cash (BCH), which could be the best option at the moment if you need *"USD right away"*. BitPay's currently supported currencies thru their RestAPI: https://bitpay.com/currencies